# Is there a way to block all cookies in html header

Tags: html, cookies

I'm using a online web builder to create my website. Once the site is published, it automatically sets their (web builders) third party cookies (google analytics, etc). There is no way to disable it in the platform.

However, under the new EU law, you are not supposed to download any cookies to the users computer, without their prior consent.

I can modify the header html code. Is there a way to generically block all cookies in the html header of my webiste?

Comment: Can't you ask the online provider to provide the script to show acceptance?

Comment: "However, under the new EU law, you are not supposed to download any cookies to the users computer, without their prior consent." — This isn't true. The law is about the collection of personal data, which includes some data inferred by tracking users between pages, which cookies are often used to do. Cookies which don't do that aren't affected. (Google Analytics cookies *do* do that, but its important to keep in mind that this is about peoples data and no cookies in particular).

Comment: The provider currently only offers a banner to inform about the use of cookies, which is obviously not enough.

Answer (score -1):

> Is there a way to generically block all cookies in the html header of my webiste?

No.

If you think your hosting service is exposing you to legal problems, then don't try to hack around them, either talk to them so they fix the problem or find a new host.